# C# Adding a item into an arraylist if the item is not already inside that arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist, foreach

Lets say I have two lists list 1 and list 2. List one has the strings "ABCD" and List 2 has the same items as list 1 but with some additonal items "1A23C4D" and i want to combine them so that its a list containing every possible value without repeating. so i would want ABCD1234 in a 3rd list

this is what i have

```
        ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();

        list1.Add("A");
        list1.Add("B");
        list1.Add("C");
        list1.Add("D");

        ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
        list2.Add("1");
        list2.Add("A");
        list2.Add("2");
        list2.Add("3");
        list2.Add("C");
        list2.Add("4");
        list2.Add("D");

        ArrayList list3 = new ArrayList();

        foreach(var item in list1)
        {
            list3.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in list1)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in list2)
            {
                //if the item2 is not at all in the first list add it to the 3rd list
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

my reason for figuring this out is because im doing something else where i have all the software installed from one reg key in an array list and then all the software from a different reg key installed in a second arraylist and i want to create a combined list of all the software installed thats not repeating itself to be displayed. I saw things similar to this posted in other languages besides c# so i thought id ask for c#. Thank you

Comment: You really shouldn't use `ArrayList` it's a left over from before generics.   Use a `List<string>` instead.

Comment: apart from using `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList` as @juharr already pointed out, consider using `HashSet<string>` for efficient `.Contains()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ArrayList`, it's an archaic data structure from .net framework 1.0 (2002 year). Use `List<T>` instead from .net framework 2.0 and later (2005 year).

You can use Linq from .net framework 3.5 and later (2008 year) to build a list with distinct items:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
            var list2 = new List<string> { "1", "A", "2", "3", "C", "4", "D" };

            var list3 = list1.Concat(list2).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var item in list3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are some other options. If you need just an enumerable you can use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
            var list2 = new List<string> { "1", "A", "2", "3", "C", "4", "D" };

            var distinctItems = list1.Concat(list2).Distinct();

            foreach (var item in distinctItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a data structure with distinct items you can use `HashSet<string>`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
            var list2 = new List<string> { "1", "A", "2", "3", "C", "4", "D" };

            var distinctItems = new HashSet<string>(list1.Concat(list2));

            foreach (var item in distinctItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case i would say it should be `HashSet<string>` not List as that collection is specifcally designed to exclude dupes, though it doesn't affect the validity of this answer

Comment: @MikeT what if the requirement is to get a list as the result? Distinct method uses efficient data structures to perform the required operation.

Comment: i was suggesting an improvement not being critical

Comment: @MikeT edited to include other options such as `HashSet`

Comment: i was thinking more `list1.Concat(list2).ToHashSet()` though the end result is the same

Comment: @MikeT yes, that would be fine as well. For reference `ToHashSet` was introduced in .net fx 4.7.2

Comment: Thank you for your time in writing all this out for me thank you. is a hash set better than a list? i dont know anything about hash sets

Comment: @MrClayGiovanni no data structure is always better than another. You should use the data structure that better fits on the problem you need to solve. There are plenty of information about `HashSet` and hash tables which is the underlying data structure used to implement `HashSet`

Comment: @JesúsLópez Except ArrayList, List is always better than that

Comment: @MikeT. `List<object>` is not much better than `ArrayList`. Is it?